# Xcode: TextView scrolls quickly to top or bottom only

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview

I'm sorry if the question is too trivial but I am completely new to xcode. 
I have a textview added to my view that has quite a lot of text within. When I run the project, I can't to scroll it properly - textview is shiften as long as I hold it by mouse/finger and go back to top when I release my mouse/finger. When I try to scroll it by much with a quick move - it goes quickly to the very bottom of the textview. It looks like top and bottom act as strong magnets.
How can I make it working that when I scroll the textview slightly, it stops there? I checked some properties like bounces and other but I didn't make it working as I wanted. I'm not sure if it is important info but I defined the textview as outlet, assigned @property and synthetized it.

I tried to browse the forum but couln't find the answer for it. Thanks for any help.
In thouchesBegan method I have:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches WithEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if (text1.editing) {
[text1 resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches WithEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Man there is the problem. As you touch it tries to get out of the editing mode if it is in editing mode. Just once comment the if statement and run the application and try to scroll textview :)

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out. Text1 is a textfield that I use in my view. It may be that!

Comment: I removed that code and it is Still the same. I will leave it for now and come to the problem later.

Answer (score 0):

Here You need To check whether You written some code Which Move The `UITextView` On `Moving` The Finger,I Guess So. You need To check Your `TouchEvents` Methods ...,if So then You need to Fix that Code

These Are the `TouchEvents` Methods,DO check in these Methods.

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Ok if you have nothing written inside these methods related to `UITextView`,I would say you should take a view of properties of that `UITextView` as below Image depicts.

Please Have A Look At this AGain.

[image]

**EDIT**:Please Make SUre You have Created The `UITextView` With `Sufficient Size`.

I hope It WOuld Help You dude..!!!!!

Comment: I have all three checkbox checked. Still nothing. In TouchBegin method, I had some code to disable a keybord. Nothing else...

Comment: @RobertWojtczak i was not saying to add code of `TouchEvent Method`.please put some code here on Your Question....

Comment: Hmmm... My wife is using my laptop now (do you allow for such things?). I will post my code later.

Comment: @RobertWojtczak No Problem .Don't try to take back your Laptop form Your Wife, YOu know the Consequences of this,hahahhahahahh
Never Mind Dude.!!!!....i am waiting....!!!!.Please see the Bottom of my edited Answer...!!!

Comment: I don't quite know how to control size. Size Inspector? Matbe this is a problem. It looks I need the textview twice as high as the screen is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
yourTextView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;
```

or in your xib check the Paging Enabled property.